# withCount() is not working acccording to filters applied in when()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10, laravel-eloquent-resource

Have problem with this is [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) not changing after [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#conditional-clauses) is applied. For example, without `when()`, `transaction_count` is 5000, and after `when()` is applied, it still remains 5000. It should change according to the filter applied in `when()`.

```php
public function allUsers(Request $request)
{
    $date = $request->input('date');
    $location = $request->input('location');

    $users = User::when(!empty($date), function ($query) use ($date) {
        return $query->whereRelation('transactions', 'date', '=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));
    })->when($location, function ($query) use ($location) {
        return $query->whereRelation('transactions', 'location', '=', $location);
    })->withCount(['transactions'])->get();

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Comment: any `with()` method need its own filters independently from `where()` methods, not only `withCount()`. Treat it as a second independent query (which is exactly what it is)

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, `whereRelation()` executes a second query, separately, and `withCount()` executes a subquery within the same one.

Instead of `whereRelation()`, try to use `join()`

Instead of:

```
return  $query->whereRelation('transactions', 'date', '=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));
```

Try:

```
return $query->join('transactions', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.user_id')
    ->where('transactions.date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to place your withCount function inside the closure of when function, then only it will count the data based on your condition, else it will always return the whole transaction_count of 5000,

you need to change your query something like below.

```
public function allUsers(Request $request)
{
        $date = $request->input('date');
        $location = $request->input('location');

        $users = User::when($date, fn($q) => $q->withCount(['transactions'=> fn($qr) => $qr->where('date', '=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) )) ]) )
                        ->when($location, fn($q) => $q->withCount(['transactions'=> fn($qr) => $qr->where( 'location', '=', $location ) ]) )
                        ->when(!$date && !$location, fn($q) => $q->withCount('transactions') )
                        ->get();

        return response()->json($users);
}
```